# FiddlerCore as Tunneling Proxy / Gateway on Server?

Tags: fiddlercore

Can FiddlerCore be used as a tunneling proxy (gateway) on a server?  A client wants me to build a proxy server for ALL PROTOCOLS with an incredibly simplified web-based GUI.  They want to filter on client/destination IP address as well as port number with no inspection of the content.  I have looked at several technologies to build on top of... WFP (Windows Filter Platform), Mentalis, Komodia, FiddlerCore, etc.  I am most attracted to FiddlerCore but I have just discovered it.  I'm also fairly new to the whole proxy concept.  I am trying to understand if it would be possible to wrap FiddlerCore in a Windows Service (if it doesn't already have one) and load a config with these filters OR watch for connection requests and kill any that fail to match certain rules.

Answer (score 1):

No, absolutely not. FiddlerCore is a tool for capturing and modifying HTTP and HTTPS traffic within a .NET application. It cannot be used to work with other types of traffic, nor can it be used as a proxy service.

What your client is describing is not a proxy server. It is a firewall.

Comment: FiddlerCore *is* a proxy, but your answer is otherwise correct.